Angular + Firebase: How to Setup AuthGuard?
My authGuard always returns false because Firebase takes some miliseconds to change currentUserSig() to true. Can anyone help?
// auth.guard.ts
import { inject } from "@angular/core"
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service"
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

export const authGuard = () => {
  const authService = inject(AuthService);
  const router = inject(Router);

  if (authService.currentUserSig()) {
    return true
  } else {
    router.navigate(['/login'])
    return false;
  }
}

// app.routes.ts
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';
import { authGuard } from './auth/auth.guard';


export const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [authGuard]},
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent,},
    {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent,},
];

This is what handles user authentication
// auth.service.ts
import { Injectable, inject, signal } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, from } from "rxjs";
import { Auth, 
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword, 
    signInWithEmailAndPassword, 
    signOut, 
    updateProfile, 
    user 
} from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { UserInterface } from "./user.interface";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
    firebaseAuth = inject(Auth)
    user$ = user(this.firebaseAuth);
    currentUserSig = signal<UserInterface | null | undefined>(undefined)

    register(
        email: string, 
        username: string, 
        password: string
        ) : Observable<void> {
        const promise = createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            this.firebaseAuth, 
            email, 
            password
            ).then(response => updateProfile(response.user, {displayName: username}))

            return from(promise);
    }

    login(
        email: string,
        password: string
    ) : Observable<void> {
        const promise = signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            this.firebaseAuth,
            email,
            password
        ).then(() => {});

        return from(promise);
    }

    logout(): Observable<void>{
        const promise = signOut(this.firebaseAuth);
        
        return from(promise);
    }
}

I don't know how to resolve this issue since most solutions deal with deprecated methods (i.e. canActivate) and I couldn't figure out from documentation.

I haven't really figured out signals yet, but it seems to me that it won't work like yours.
However, Firebase has a separate method only for checking whether the user is logged in.
In my project, I implemented this method in the service and this service directly in the guard.
This is the working version, please take a look, it might be useful for you.
import { inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivateFn, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { map, Observable, tap } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PermissionsService {
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}
  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.checkIsUserLogin();
  }
  private checkIsUserLogin(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      map(user => !!user)
    );
  }
}

export const authGuard: CanActivateFn = (): Observable<boolean> => {
  const permissionsService= inject(PermissionsService);
  const router = inject(Router);

  return permissionsService.canActivate().pipe(
    tap((permission: boolean) => {
      if (!permission) {
        router.navigate(['/login']);
      }
    })
  );

};

